# Pentaho Kettle/ETL integration with Subversion or Git

Tags: git, svn, pentaho

We are using Pentaho ETL (aka Kettle). Pentaho has a built in *enterprise repository* for versioning. However, it is very poor. First, there's no way to go through an entire Pentaho project looking for changes. Each file is its own individual change. Second, there doesn't appear to be a way to tag an entire release.

We *could* use a file based system for storing our Pentaho objects. Jobs will end with a `.kjb` suffix and *Transformations* will end with a `.ktr` suffix. If that file system happened to be a Git or Subversion workspace, we could checkout/push/sync a revision of the Pentaho project, do the changes, and then commit/push those changes back to the repository.

However, there doesn't appear to be a way to check in and out of files from Pentaho itself like you can with Eclipse, or VisualStudio, or any other IDE environment.

Is there a way to integrate Subversion with Pentaho? Is it possible to use Eclipse (which not only integrates with Subversion and Git, but also integrates with Jira and Rally) with Pentaho ETL/Kettle?

Comment: we use it just like you describe in the second/third paragraph. plain files, no ide integration.

Comment: @mnagel - Is there a problem using it without built in check in and out? Do people forget to do commits? Integrated IDEs usually have direct integration into version control. I was hoping that Eclipse had an integration, but doesn't.

Comment: people are no more or less likely to forget to commit than in other cases. personally i only ever really used standalone vcs, so i do not miss integration, others might. our team knows their version control and we use version control for deployment, so forgetting to push is not a problem. i cannot tell how often people forget to pull and work against old versions when developing. the one thing that could be improved upon is merging, the kjb/ktr files are autogenerated xml and cannot really be edited concurrently because you merging them using a text-based mergetool just doesnt work.

Comment: we just use Kitchen and command line subversion.

Comment: @Andrew That would actually be my preference. The problem is that our guy-on-the-spot feels that moving between Kettle and the command line (including TortoiseSVN) would be _too confusing_ for the devs. It's why I was hoping for built-in integration. There are more serious issues here. For example, they have other non-Kettle projects with no version control at all. So, I'm not going to fight him on this. At least there is _some_ version history, and the Kettle database is being backed up.